# standard error of an estimate of fraction of objects with a known binary probability

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution, standard-error

Lets have a group of N people that can be either men M or women W (or in general objects that can be 0 or 1).  For each person $i$ we have an estimate of probability $P_i$ from <0,1> that it is a man. We want to estimate the proportion of men in the group (which must be a number from <0,1> too). The expected value is obviously
$$
E(M)=\frac{\sum P_i}{N}
$$
However, how to estimate the standard error of E(M)? Using the formula for $\sigma$ of a binomial distribution, I thought it should be
$$
\sigma^2=\frac{\sum P_i(1-P_i)}{N}
$$
but looking at the $\sigma$ estimates with some simple examples of a few people, I think that is not correct.  Any hints?

Comment: Can you include an example you looked at with small $N$?

Comment: If you assume each case is independent of the others, then the expected number of women is $\sum P_i$ with variance $\sum P_i(1-P_i)$, and so the expected proportion is is $\frac1N \sum P_i$ with variance $\frac1{N^2}\sum P_i(1-P_i)$

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you might be right that I just stupidly missed the square root of N, thanks for pointing that out.